# XCode 4 Running the Leaks Instrument

Tags: instruments, xcode4

This might be a silly question.

How do I run an application with an Instrument in XCode 4 such as Leaks?

I do not see the option like I have in the past, and I have looked around, and either I missed it somewhere, or it is right in front of my face.

Thanks

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Click and hold on the run button, and choose the profile option.

[image: Profile]

You can also edit the profile scheme to make it use debug builds when profiling. To do this, go to edit scheme by click on the dropdown next to the stop button:

[image: edit scheme location]

Then select profile item on the sidebar, then make sure 'Build configuration' is set to debug.

Comment: You sir are AWESOME!  That was it!

Answer (score 15):

as jeff said, that is 1 way you could do it.. other way with keyboard shortcuts is press cmd + I and this runs the profiler and after that you can choose leaks...